# why I can use the string function length() when the <string> isn't included in C++?

Tags: c++, string

The code is shown following, the string library has been commented, but the program still work well

```
#include<iostream>
//#include<string>   // the string library has been commented 
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        string str;
        int num = 0;
        cin>>str;
        int len = str.length();    //the function length is used here!
        for (int j =0; j< len; j++){
           if (str[j] >='0' && str[j] <='9')
               num ++;
        } 
    cout<<num<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How could you use `string` without including the library?

Comment: [This shows that it doesn't work](http://rextester.com/PHCGB87223).  If you want to use `std::string`, then `#include` it.  It doesn't matter if by chance your compiler just happens to include <string> internally somewhere in the compiler's set of #includes, you're to assume nothing and always #include the file that prototypes or defines the functions and classes you're using in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because internally `iostream` includes `string`.

Includes are transitive, and some of the dependencies might be compiler dependent, while others will be the same on all platforms (one such example is that including `map` will make `pair` available, as it depends on it directly).

The dependency between `string` and `iostream` isn't defined anywhere, so while it might work on some compilers, you shouldn't depend on it.

Comment: And one famous compiler that is probably used by many, if not most programmers is `Visual C++`.  The code will refuse to compile with any version of Visual C++, including the latest version.